# Is the SVNKit Client Adapter 1.8.12.1 compatible withe the SVNKit Library 1.9.0.r10652

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnkit

Our server team upgraded subversion from 1.6.x to 1.9.x and I need to upgrade the client software to match.

I downloaded a new copy of eclipse oxygen 4.7.0 64 bit for windows.
I installed the latest SVNKIT from http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.9.x
And I installed the latest subclipse from the eclipse marketplace.

The following items are now currently installed.

Subclipse 4.2.3.201707071932
  Subversion Revision Graph 4.2.0.1
  SVNKit Client Adapter 1.8.12.1
  SVNKit Library 1.9.0.r10652

I started eclipse, set the SVN Interface Client to the only available option of "SVNKit v1.8.12.10533", and proceed to browse my repository from the SVN Repository tab.

All seems fine so far but before doing anything with it I am concerned about the presumed version mismatch in the SVNKit Client Adapter 1.8x and the SVNKit Library 1.9.x.  Is the 1.8.x SVNKit client adapter compatible with the SVNKit Library (1.9.x) when using a 1.9.x subversion server?  I have tried to find an upgrade to the SVNKit Client Adapter with no luck.  Is this a compatible stack or is the 1.8.x svnkit client adapter really for the 1.8.x SVNKit?

Comment: As I could not resolve the question of compatibility with SVNKit Client Adapter I resolved my question by finding a way to simply get the native JavaHL installed. The eclipse market place did not provide it and I didn't want the old versions from tigris.org. And I could not figure out how to install from the zipped updates referenced from GitHub. Installing subclipse to eclipse using the install URL refenced on github however gave me everything I needed dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest I excluded the SVNKit components and selected the JavaHL Windows Binaries.

Answer (score 1):

It should work OK.  Subclipse is written to the JavaHL Interface and SVNKit just implements it.  It should not matter if they have released an updated version.

Comment: I have always been under the impression that the server side SVN major version (1.9.x) should match the JavaHL (or in this case SVNKit) major version (1.9.x). Since the SVNKit Client Adapter is the interface between subclipse and JavaHL should the SVNKit Client Adapter also match the major version of SVNKit to ensure compatability all the way down the stack?

Comment: The server version is totally irrelevant other than the features you might care about. All 1.x clients can talk to all 1.y servers.  The only issue on the client is API compatibility between the layers and the 1.9.x version would implement all of the API that is being used by Subclipse.